# Como cambiar de fragmento desde el adaptador de un recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Este movimiento ya lo tengo en otro layout y me cambia de fragmento sin problemas, el problema ahora es que lo intento hacer desde una lista (Alert Dialog) y que desde aqui me mande al fragmento que debe ir

```
builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        tractor = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);


                        FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new MovimientosLayout());


                        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        trans.addToBackStack(null);

                        trans.commit();

                    }
                });
                builderSingle.show();
```

Este es mi codigo que utilizo pero al momento de querer mostrarlo me lo manda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me deja el fragmento de home detras, siendo que cuando lo ejecuto desde el buscador(asi se llama) realmente me quita el fragmento de la vista

Comment: Veo que tratas de realizarlo no desde el Adapter en sí, si no desde un Dialog al realizar clic...

Comment: Asi es ... es algo complejo pero asi se ha pedido

Comment: El código que presentas esta en tu Activity?